# Convert a row with multiple quantity to multiple rows of single quantity while joining another table with partial data

Tags: sql-server, join, row, partial

I have 2 tables, one with the ID and its count and the other with the names belonging to the respective IDs. They need to be joined so that the end result is a table with count of 1 in each row and the respective names next to them. Note that the number of names in table 2 is less than the count in table 1 for the same ID in some cases.

Table 1

```
ID  | Count
-----------
100 | 3
101 | 2
102 | 4
```

Table 2

```
ID  | Name
----------
100 | abc       
100 | def       
101 | ghi       
101 | jkl       
102 | mno       
102 | pqr       
102 | stu
```

Result

```
ID  | Count | Name
------------------
100 | 1     | abc
100 | 1     | def
100 | 1     |
101 | 1     | ghi
101 | 1     | jkl
102 | 1     | mno
102 | 1     | pqr
102 | 1     | stu
102 | 1     |
```

I'm using TSQL for this and my current query converts table 1 into multiple rows in the result table; then it inserts individual names from table 2 into the result table through a loop. I'm hoping there must be a simpler or more efficient way to do this as the current method takes considerable amount of time. If there is, please let me know.

Comment: Is it ever the case that the number of names in table 2 is more than the count in table 1 for the same ID? If so, how to decide which names to omit?

Comment: Yes, Ideally there should be equal number of names in T2 as the count in T1 but sometimes the names are not up to date. So, once the query runs out of names the subsequent IDs need to remain blank

Comment: The names in T2 will never be more than the count in T1. The names may be less but never more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind for me involves using a Number table, which you could create (as a one-time task) like this:

```
CREATE TABLE numbers (
    ID INT
)

DECLARE @CurrentNumber INT, @MaxNumber INT
SET @MaxNumber = 100 -- Choose a value here which you feel will always be greater than MAX(table1.Count)
SET @CurrentNumber = 1

WHILE @CurrentNumber <= @MaxNumber
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO numbers VALUES (@CurrentNumber)
    SET @CurrentNumber = @CurrentNumber + 1
END
```

Once you have a numbers table, you can solve this problem like this:

```
SELECT  one.ID,
        1 AS [Count],
        ISNULL(two.Name,'') AS Name
FROM table1 one
JOIN numbers n ON n.ID <= CASE WHEN one.[Count] >= (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table2 two WHERE one.ID = two.ID)
                            THEN one.[Count]
                            ELSE (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table2 two WHERE one.ID = two.ID)
                          END
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   ID, 
                    Name,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) AS RecordNo
            FROM table2) two ON one.ID = two.ID
                            AND two.RecordNo = n.ID
```

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to accept and/or upvote the answer if it was helpful.